# How to defeat the fontification of colour literals in css-mode?

Tags: font-lock, css

Emacs css-mode is fontifying my colour literals.  For example:

[image: Two colour literals coloured]

This makes the text harder to read.

I tried to defeat it with the following in my `.emacs`.
(Note: this matches on ‘hsl’ because those are the only literals I actually use.)

```
(font-lock-add-keywords nil
 '(
   ("color: *\\(hsla?(.*)\\)" 1 'default t) ; Colour literal
   )
 )
```

This fails.  I can override the fontification of other things,
but somehow these colour literals are override proof.

How can I defeat this unwanted fontification?

Comment: I'm not on my computer right now, but I'd start by looking in the customization group for CSS mode. There's a very big chance the feature you want to disable is not a product of font-lock activity, but is done afterwards.

Comment: @wvxvw I never use the customization UI.
But now I see what to look for in the `.el`:
‘[defcustom](https://github.com/cpitclaudel/emacs/blob/master/lisp/textmodes/css-mode.el#L1100)’.
Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelAllan Whether you use `customize-group`, `apropos-variable`, or just completion in `describe-variable`, you have several good methods for discovering which options are available without resorting to searching for `defcustom` in the `.el` file. Obviously you can do that, but it probably shouldn't be your first port of call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `css` <kbd>RET</kbd>

would inform you about:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `css-fontify-colors`

```
css-fontify-colors is a variable defined in `css-mode.el'.
Its value is t

  This variable is safe as a file local variable if its value
  satisfies the predicate `booleanp'.

Documentation:
Whether CSS colors should be fontified using the color as the background.
When non-`nil', a text representing CSS color will be fontified
such that its background is the color itself.  E.g., #ff0000 will
be fontified with a red background.

You can customize this variable.

This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
version 26.1 of Emacs.
```